# First iPhone, what should I Do?

Tags: iphone

So, I've decided to go for an iPhone 4. But since I am new to the whole iPhone thing, what are the things that I should know, to make the maximum use of the device?

Some of the questions I would like to know the answer:

1. what are the apps I should install?
2. How do I charge the battery?
3. The temperature the iPhone should be exposed to in order to prolong the lifespan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) That entirely depends on what you want to do. There are a bunch of app recommendation discussions here based around games, productivity, etc. Rather than rehash them, I'd suggest searching those out.

2) Plug it into a USB port on your computer. The phone also comes with a wall adapter for the USB cable so you can charge it from a wall socket.

3) Don't stick it in the oven or the freezer and you should be fine.

Comment: what about the screen? Let's say if my hands are oily and I touch the screen, will that make the screen oily too?

Comment: Make sure you don’t blend it: http://www.willitblend.com/videos.aspx?video=iphone

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui - As long as you can still hold onto it, it'll be okay. When it gets too slippery to hold, you'll want to wipe it on your shirt.

Comment: The oleophobic screen on the iPhone is surprisingly awesome at keeping itself clean, and easily wiped off if it gets dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a handy "iPhone Temperate Zone" chart on their [iPhone battery](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html) page.

As for what apps to install: the reason apps are user-installable is because everybody wants different ones!  But also, if you're in Malaysia, you probably have a different selection of available apps in your App Store from most other users here, anyway.